# simplemembershipprovider using applicationname

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Does `SimpleMembershipProvider` use `ApplicationName` in anyway? I don't see any tables that will help it link in the documentation. I don't see any tables generated or linked in the actual source code itself,

[GitHub - ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs)

But isn't membership inherently bound to an `ApplicationName`? Or is there any workaround I can use to get this associated with. Basically I have an application and an admin portal, I want to use the same tables, but use different applications to identify different users and roles.

Thanks,
Fahad

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom UserProfile table for storing such information. There is a very good information on asp.net blog: [Customize the SimpleMembership in ASP.NET MVC 4.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2012/11/15/customize-the-simplemembership-in-asp-net-mvc-4-0.aspx)

You may also consider migrate your project to MVC 5 and use OWIN authentication

Comment: I went ahead and implemented my own custom simple membership provider. I wanted to separate admin users with normal app users, so basically SMP doesn't provide that as its a simplistic version of the membership provider.

Answer (score 0):

No they moved away from the idea of partitioning users by ApplicationName (it seems a strange use case).

The preferred way would now be to just specify different connection strings and use separate databases (this assumes you have multiple apps).

If you want to partition users within a single application, you would ideally have 2 providers and direct calls accordingly, but `SimpleMembershipProvider` doesn't support non-default providers so you can only use one. You can overcome this, take a look at [BetterMembership.Net](http://thecodeking.github.io/BetterMembership.Net/), this supports multiple instances of `SimpleMembershipProvider` from a single application.